# Why does an open server-sent event prevent other SSE, POST or GET?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post, server-sent-events

When I open a SSE (a simple one), all the others ajax requests (POST, GET, SSE) are waiting for the closure of the SSE.

Does it normal? What should I do to let requests run in same time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If this is in a local development environment it may be that your application server is configured to only process one request at a time.  That would block any other requests from happening until your SSE connection closes.